# Can Dell P2421DC charge 16" MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, charging

The Dell P2421DC [product manual](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics_accessories/esuprt_electronics_accessories_monitors/dell-p2421dc-monitor_user%27s-guide_en-us.pdf) says it can deliver 65W via USB-C.

Can it charge the 16" MacBook Pro?